# Align Menu and Content CSS

Tags: css

I have made this CSS layout, but I can't properly aling the menu to the content.

```
body{
    margin:0;
    background:url(wb_menu_bg.jpg) repeat-y;

}



#bg-left {
    color:#FFF;
    width:225px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
 }

#content {
margin:0 0 0 230px;
}

 #menu8 {
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#menu8 li a {
   text-decoration: none;
   voice-family: "\"}\""; 
   voice-family: inherit;
}

 #menu8 li a:link, #menu8 li a:visited {
    color: #777;
    display: block;
    background: url(images/menu8.gif);
    padding: 8px 0 0 20px;
}

#menu8 li a:hover {
     color: #257EB7;
    background: url(images/menu8.gif) 0 -32px;
    padding: 8px 0 0 25px;
 }

#menu8 li a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background: url(images/menu8.gif) 0 -64px;
    padding: 8px 0 0 25px;
 }

#menu8 ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

 h2 {
   font-size:18px;
  }

#inlogform{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-170 0 0 -180px;
color:white;
 }

 #inlogform td
 {
    color:white;
 }

 #bg{

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url(boekenkast.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
  }

#inlogform a:link {color:#FFFFFF;}      /* unvisited link */
#inlogform a:visited {color:#FFFFFF;}  /* visited link */
#inlogform a:hover {color:#FFFFFF;}  /* mouse over link */
#inlogform a:active {color:#FFFFFF;}  /* selected link */
```

But the alignment is not what I wanted.

Situation now:
http://i41.tinypic.com/ncmtsn.png

Desired situation
http://i39.tinypic.com/30ufzok.png

Can someone tell me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try adding a

```
float:left;
```

to your menu

e.g.

```
#bg-left {
    color:#FFF;
    width:225px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
 }
```

assuming #bg-left is your menu

Otherwise are you able to provide a link to your html or site?

Answer (score 1):

you should using in your css file:

```
.BG-LEFT{
float:left;
}
```

for read more about float:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Thank you I will read the w3s artical for further information

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement `float: left` on the things that you want to sit next to each other (`.bg-left` and `#inlogform`). or have `float: left` on the left hand element, and `float: right` on the right hand element, given that the parent container will be wide/narrow enough to position them close to each other.